# 80% Circle Border

Tags: css, css-shapes

Right now I have a Circle which serves as a wrapper for my icons. However, I was wondering if it was possible to not show the "full" circle but rather 80% of it. The provide picture shows the desired result.

My Wrapper Class:

```
.icon-wrapper {
position: relative;
border: 2px solid black;
padding: $icon-padding;
border-radius: 50%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at eg using backgrounds like conic and/or radial gradients as a simple way of doing it in CSS only?

Comment: There are SVG-based solutions for this if that helps

Answer (score 0):

You use either `:after` or `:before` Pseudo-element.

```css
span {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

span::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  height: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  top: -5px;
  left: 8px;
}
```

```html
<span></span>
```

---

In order to achieve the reqired result, adjust the width, height, top, and left properties of the `:after` element.

Read more here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements